# Control AWS Lambda source IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a simple Lambda function the its job is to make HTTP GET to a certain server.

I need to run many copies (hundreds) of the function **at the same time** and I want to have a **distinct source IP address** for each HTTP GET coming from each Lambda.

My questions:

1. How do I make sure that each 'copy' of the Lambda function will have its own IP address?
2. How do I use boto API invoke call in order to tell AWS that I need N concurrent copies of my Lambda? I am looking [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke) but I can not find the argument that sets the number of concurrent copies.

Thanks

Avishay

As for question #2 I am using the following code in order to invoke N concurrent copies of the Lambda function.

```
 import boto3, json
 from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

 N = 5
 unique_ips = set()

 lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda', region_name='us-west-2')


 def _lambda_caller(idx):
     test_event = dict(idx=idx)
     res = lambda_client.invoke(
        FunctionName='SimpleHTTPGetter',
        InvocationType='RequestResponse',
        Payload=json.dumps(test_event),
     )
     data = json.loads(res['Payload']._raw_stream.data)
     print('Thread {} is done'.format(idx))
     unique_ips.add(data['body'])

 with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=N) as executor:
     for i in range(0,N):
         future = executor.submit(_lambda_caller,i)
     executor.shutdown()
    print('Done')
```

My Lambda code (short version)

```
import json
import socket    

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print('-- HTTP Client started')
    hostname = socket.gethostname()    
    ip = socket.gethostbyname(hostname) 
    print('My IP address is {}:'.format(ip))
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": ip
    }
```

Comment: Is the server you want to `GET` from inside your VPC?  Lambda's would need a NAT to connect to devices outside your VPC and therefore would not have unique IP addresses.

Comment: kenlukas - the server is inside the VPC

Comment: Why do you wish to do this? Normally, when people ask this question, they are trying to scrape websites against that site's Terms and Conditions by making it look like requests are coming from many locations. This is not a behaviour we wish to encourage on StackOverflow.

Comment: John Rotenstein - The reason I am doing this is for **internal** research project in my company. Any technical suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a VPC, Make sure you attach a subnet that allows internet access. And then attach a security policy to your lambda.
Step by Step here:
https://medium.com/@philippholly/aws-lambda-enable-outgoing-internet-access-within-vpc-8dd250e11e12

Comment: Ryan B - I have read the article carefully but could not find how does it answer  my original question which is: _How do I make sure that each 'copy' of the Lambda function will have its own IP address?_ Am I missing anything?